# Movie where a female scientist is capturing souls

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find a movie I saw on Netflix probably between 2012 and 2016.

The plot of the movie is: a female scientist is brought to some sort of underground military bunker where they perform experiments to capture people's souls. They capture people's souls inside of a large glass box by bringing in dying people and the glass chamber would keep the soul trapped inside. The main character is a woman; and at the end she is killed inside the box; and her soul is captured. There is another lead character who is a man leading the facility. I think she tried to end the experiments, which is why he was the one who put her in the box.

Comment: Not your film, but it sounds like you'd enjoy *The Asphyx*

Comment: Do you know if the film was originally in English, or another language?

Comment: I think it was originally in English. Or maybe British.

Comment: Was there a remake to the asphyx.  That sounds just like the movie I saw but was more modern than 1972.

Answer (score 9):

Although it doesn't quite match the time frame or all the details, this does sound a lot like the 2017 short film "[Laboratory Conditions](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6956566/)," starring Marissa Tomei and Minnie Driver.  The entire seventeen-minute film is available on YouTube.

[This review](https://www.indieshortsmag.com/reviews/2020/03/laboratory-conditions-exploring-the-fundamental-questions-of-human-existence/) has a partial plot summary:

> The film begins with a low tense, dramatic music, hushed up voices, and dim-lit setting, all conjuring up an atmosphere of mystery.  Dr Emma Holloway (Marisa Tomei) is in search of her missing deceased patient.  She notices an oddly-behaving ambulance and follows it, which leads her to a huge laboratory where an experiment is to be carried out on the stolen patient, still alive but barely, under highly regulated and monitored conditions.  All this is under the supervision of a scientist, Marjorie Cane (Minnie Driver).  She, along with Robbins (Paulo Costanzo) and a bunch of others, wishes to determine the exact moment when the soul leaves the body.

The experimental procedure does involve placing people in a glass-walled box that is supposed to be impervious to souls—thus trapping the souls in the box after their body's deaths.  And at the end, one of the female leads does indeed get trapped inside the experimental chamber, although not quite according to the sequence of events described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The movie is called ***[Spectral](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2106651/)*** from 2016. It’s on Netflix right now.

> A sci-fi/thriller story centered on a special-ops team that is dispatched to fight supernatural beings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how this matches the film described in the question. It would help other users determine how likely this answer is to be correct or not.